# didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not getting called when the cell is not loaded completely

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have collection view inside that i'm loading images (image has long press gesture recognizer).
When the collection view cell is not loaded completely didSelectItemAtIndexPath method is not getting called.

I scrolled down and load everything then i put that cell in a position(screen shot attached) now the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method is getting called[image: In this position the didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not getting called]

cellForItemAtIndexPath code below: -

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    modelProductDetails=[self.productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PLPCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"plpcollectiocellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imgview addGestureRecognizer:longPress];



    cell.conlblofferpriceheight.constant=21;
    cell.shareView.alpha = 0;

    double actualPrice = [modelProductDetails.price doubleValue];// striked out
    double offerPrice = [modelProductDetails.final_price doubleValue];//will be in red instead of special price

    cell.lblitemPrice.text = [MyShoppingCartViewController displayFormattedPrice: modelProductDetails.price];


    if (offerPrice < actualPrice && offerPrice != 0) {

        NSMutableAttributedString *priceString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,cell.lblitemPrice.text]];

        [priceString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [priceString length])];

        cell.lblitemofferprice.text = [MyShoppingCartViewController displayFormattedPrice:modelProductDetails.final_price];

        [cell.lblitemPrice  setAttributedText:  priceString];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell.lblitemofferprice setText:nil];
    }


    cell.lblIteeTitle.text=modelProductDetails.brand;
    cell.lblitemDescription.text=modelProductDetails.name;
    cell.lblIteeTitle.text=modelProductDetails.manufacturer_value;

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:modelProductDetails.small_image];
    [cell.imgview sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGes = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGestures:)];
    longPressGes.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
    longPressGes.allowableMovement = 100.0f;
    [cell.imgview addGestureRecognizer:longPressGes];
    [cell.shareButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.addToWishlistButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.addToWishlistButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addToWishlistAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.shareButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.addToWishlistButton.tag=indexPath.row;

    return cell;

}
```

Additional info: Only the cells in right side has the problem cells in left side is working fine

Comment: is there any button in the cell ?

Comment: @sourav no button inside the cell

Comment: @Fogmeister you want to see cellforitematindexpath code

Comment: then check your datasource is added properly or not .

Comment: Any code. A screenshot is no use for debugging why code is not working :)

Comment: @Fogmeister when the cell is not completely visible and not loaded before the  didselect is not getting called

Comment: comment out longpress gesture and then check it is added multiple times as this is reuse

Comment: @techloverr where should i write the gesture  code

Comment: @vijeesh are you using tapgesture to your view ?

Comment: just first remove and check then I'll give you proper way

Comment: ok, i will do that and check

Comment: @techloverr commented out that part and same thing is happening

Comment: @vijeesh can you share your code?

Comment: @vijeesh have you removed `[cell.imgview addGestureRecognizer:longPressGes];` both times?

Comment: yes i removed that part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106919/discussion-between-vijeesh-and-techloverr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is a delegate method of `UICollectioView`, make sure you bind the `UICollectionView` `Datasource` and `Delegate` properly.

Comment: i have added data source n delegate didSelectItemAtIndexPath is working in other scenario....